# Input datetime-local no toma atributo min

Tags: angularjs

Estoy ocupando un input type `datetime-local` con angularjs y desde el controlador obtengo la fecha de hoy y le sumo un dia más y me gustaria que esa fecha fuera la fecha minima de mi input asi el usuario no puede elegir una fecha inferior a esta.

```
<input type="datetime-local" min="{{fecha_minima.value}}" ng-model="fecha_minima.value">
```

Y en mi controlador

```
$scope.fecha_minima = new Date();
$scope.fecha_minima = {
    value : new Date($scope.fecha_minima.getFullYear(),  $scope.fecha_minima.getMonth(),  $scope.fecha_minima.getDate()+1, $scope.fecha_minima.getHours(), $scope.fecha_minima.getMinutes())
};
```

Sin embargo esto no funciona, me permite elegir fechas inferiores a la que le doy, pero si yo pongo en el atributo `min` una fecha en concreto esto si funciona, por ejemplo `min="2016-11-21T00:00:00"` el calendario bloquea los dias anteriores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pásale la fecha a esta función y te devolverá el formato que necesitas para el *min* del *input type datetime-local*. Sería algo como `formatToDateTimeLocal(new Date())`:

```
function formatToDateTimeLocal (date){
        var isoDate = date.toISOString();
        return isoDate.split(".")[0];
}
```

Comment: Gracias, esto sirvio!